# Windows 7 loader problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, windows-7

i have installed ubuntu on a partition and then i went to windows 7 and installed "easybcd" software to make grub as default loader and i also selected skip boot menu or something like that. From then on when i try to boot windows 7 from grub my system restarts and continues loading from grub. My windows boot loader menu is missing.  i have attached a picture which clearly shows i have windows 7 on a partition.Please help ![

[image]

Comment: the picture is linked in "enter image description here " or here is the link    i dont know why the image is not added in the post      " http://i.stack.imgur.com/kwuPv.jpg  "

Comment: Installing Windows 7 first is always the best option.

Comment: Different question, same answer.  Run the steps in this link under [Repair Grub after Installing Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/831127/dual-boot-dont-work-on-windows-10/831175#831175)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! "selected skip boot menu or something like that." Isn't very clear (at least to me) please [edit] your post to provide accurate information. You may benefit from reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: With Windows 7 you don't need EasyBCD or any other Windows bootloader editors if you use Grub as the primary bootloader.

Comment: Easybcd can only chainload to Grub. Windows-boot-loader has changed or is damaged now.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Ubuntu and install a program called boot-repair.
Install it by opening the terminal then typing this in:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

To open it by either typing in the terminal:`boot-repair`,or from the launcher.
Then click on recommended repair and follow the instruction.
Hope this helped!